# Xna AudioEmitter & AudioLIstener

Tags: c#, xna, audio, xact

Can you tell me how exactly does that thing works. I mean how audioListnere knows, that audioEmitter is playing something ? We are making game with few friends, and i am responsible for the audio, and i am collection all kind of knowledge. I apprieciate all kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article about [Dynamic Audio](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/dynamic_audio) from [XNA Creators](http://create.msdn.com) website.  They also have a [3D Audio](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/3d_audio) sample.

There is also the [SoundLab](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/soundlab) with 170 audio files which maybe a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for that. I read those two articles, but i forgot there was that SoundLab. Will be enormously helpful ;)